# Using Uploadify with Codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter, uploadify, codeigniter-2

I am trying to use Uploadify v2.1.4 with Codeigniter v2.1. I understand there are issues with flash not sending the session data to the controller which resorts in codeigniter returning a http 302 error instead of the upload script.

I've seen various solutions out there but they are all for older versions of the framework, particularly codeigniter. Has anyone found a recent solution to integrate uploadify with CI? I can get the script to work by placing the upload script outside the CI directory, but I want to utilise CI functions so it isn't a good solution for me.

To confirm the error message I receive is 'HTTP 302'... i.e. the uploadify script is forbidden from accessing /a/reports/uploadify

This is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/swf/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/a/reports/uploadify',
    'cancelImg' : '/img/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/uploads/originals', 
    'auto'      : true,
    'fileExt'   : '*.jpg;*.pdf;*.doc',
    'fileDesc'  : 'jpg, pdf or doc',
    'hideButton': false,
    'removeCompleted':false
  });
```

Any my controller

```
class Reports extends MY_Controller
{
public function uploadify()
{
    log_message('info','uploadify method being called');

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    log_message('info', 'File Upload: Temp file created '.$tempFile);
    log_message('info', 'File Upload: Target path for upload '.$targetPath);
    log_message('info', 'File Upload: Target file for upload '.$targetFile);

    $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
    $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
    $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
    $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray))
    {       
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
    }
    else 
    {
        log_message('error', 'File Upload: Invalid file type uploaded ['.$fileParts['extension'].']');
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I was able to find this solution. Not the best, but still a good workaround.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/150550/